# SQL duplicates query not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I found a very similar quesiton on here copied the code changed as required and it won't run under MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  id_manufacturer,
  id_partname,
  id_model,
  cnumber,
  COUNT (*)
FROM 
  rpi_consumables
GROUP BY 
  id_manufacturer, id_partname, id_model, cnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why the syntax fails?

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '*) from    rpi_consumables group by
>   id_manufacturer, id_partname, id_mode' at line 6

Comment: for smaller performance fix, use "COUNT(*) as c" in the select statement and "HAVING c > 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no space between `COUNT` and `(*)`.

```
SELECT 
  id_manufacturer,
  id_partname,
  id_model,
  cnumber,
  COUNT(*) /* This is where the space needs to be removed */
FROM 
  rpi_consumables
GROUP BY 
  id_manufacturer, id_partname, id_model, cnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```